# Appending a template string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to append a template string to a div? I'm trying to optimise my code and currently my code is having to create element, add classes, add a text node and then append all together. I was wondering if its possible to just create a template string and then append that, to be more efficient? I don't want to wipe out the current div's html with innerHTML.

```
socket.on('coinFlip', (result) => {

    const messages = document.querySelector('#messages');
    const output = `<li class="message broadcast">${result.result}</li>`;

    messages.appendChild(output);

});
```

Current code that works is:

```
socket.on('coinFlip', (result) => {

    // Grab dialog box
    const messages = document.querySelector('#messages');

    // Render messages
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.className = "message broadcast";
    const text = document.createTextNode(`${result.result}`);
    li.appendChild(text);
    messages.appendChild(li);

});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`Element.insertAdjacentHTML(position, text)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

> The `insertAdjacentHTML()` method of the [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) interface parses the specified text as HTML or XML and inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position. It does not reparse the element it is being used on, and thus it does not corrupt the existing elements inside that element. This avoids the extra step of serialization, making it much faster than direct [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) manipulation.
>
> **Parameters**
> `position`
>     A [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) representing the position relative to the `element`;
>     must be one of the following strings:
>         - `'beforebegin'`: Before the `element` itself.
>         - `'afterbegin'`: Just inside the `element`, before its first child.
>         - `'beforeend'`: Just inside the `element`, after its last child.
>         - `'afterend'`: After the `element` itself.
>
> `text`
>     The string to be parsed as HTML or XML and inserted into the tree.

```
socket.on('coinFlip', (result) => {

    const messages = document.querySelector('#messages');
    const output = `<li class="message broadcast">${result.result}</li>`;

    messages.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", output);

});
```